# Call method in foreach with clean code

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm using DomDocument to access a HTML page and convert into a Object but every time I need to search nodes with some different tag. I want a method with the logic name as parameter, but each logic have different number of parameters.

```
public function foo(){
    $this->findTag('bar', $parameters);
}
public function findTag($logic, $parameters){
    foreach ($this->dom->getElementsByTagName($this->tag) as $node) {
        $this->$logic($node, $parameters);
    }
}
public function logic1($node, $foo, $bar){
    //something with $foo and $bar
}
public function logic2($node, $fooBar){
    //something with $fooBar
}
```

This is a bad approach? How can I make this foreach a unique function always called when needed some info from the DomObject, using a different tag.

Works after [@JustOnUnderMillions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856285/call-method-in-foreach-with-clean-code?noredirect=1#comment70897129_41856285) comment

```
class pei
{
    public function classe($nome)
    {
        $this->findTag('logic1', $nome);
    }

    public function classe2($porta, $janela)
    {
        $this->findTag('logic2', $porta, $janela);
    }

    public function findTag($logic, ...$parameters)
    {
        $array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        print_r($parameters);
        foreach ($array as $node) {
            $this->$logic($node, $parameters);
        }
    }

    public function logic1($node, $nome)
    {
        print_r($node);
        print_r($nome);
    }

    public function logic2($node, $porta)
    {
        print_r($node);
        print_r($porta[0]);
        print_r($porta[1]);
    }
}
(new pei)->classe('pablito');
(new pei)->classe2('janela1', 'janela2');
```

This is the cleanest/dry strategie to code this? I want to learn after several issues with duplicates.

Comment: PHP Version? Did you know the term `Variadic functions` http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list  like `public function logic1($node, ...$args)` and at the call `$this->$logic($node, ...$parameters);`

Comment: Seems OK to me. Is your code running well, with no notices or errors?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions this work. Is this really the cleanest/dry way to code this? I need to learn this after several issues with duplicates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from me,
rules i take from your question:

*logic name as parameter*  AND *using a different tag*

```
class pei
{
    /**
     * @param $logic array|string [logicname,tagname] or "logicname"
     * @param $arguments the argument list for the logic
     **/
    public function findTag($logic,...$arguments)
    {
        if(is_array($logic)){
          list($logic,$tag)=$logic;
        } else {
           $tag=$this->tag;//Note: your example dont show where this is coming from!?
        }

        if(!method_exists($this,$logic)){
            throw new Exception("Logic '$logic' not found!");
        }

        $result=array();
        //Note: Is also unclear where and how $this->dom is set!?
        foreach ($this->dom->getElementsByTagName($tag) as $node) {
          //here we expand the args to $arg0,$arg1,...
          $result[]= $this->{$logic}($node,...$arguments);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    //logic definitions
    public function logic1($node, $arg0){}
    public function logic2($node, $arg0, $arg1){}
    public function logic3($node, $arg0, $arg1, $arg2){}
}
```

Now we have one method that can delegate to an other method depending on parameter setup.

```
$result = (new pei($Dom))->findTag('logic1','pablito');
$result = (new pei($Dom))->findTag('logic2','janela1', 'janela2');
$result = (new pei($Dom))->findTag(['logic2','tagname'],'janela1', 'janela2');
```

- So now you can call the logic method directly or use the `findTag()` method.
- You can define as many logic methods you need
- You can use the method with logicname & tagname or only a logicname

But this is all just an example for what can be made. I would do this in another way and currently i dont get fully what kind of logic is needed here. My example shows only how to handle and deligate call of method to a sub-methods on different parameters.

Keep in mind that the example is missing server things like error handling.

Hope this gives a direction.

Comment: I have a DOM structure with a HTML page and every time is needed to make a foreach to find a element in structure.

Comment: In one case need to match a class with specific name `(new Dom)->in('div')->findClass('div_acervo')` findClass use your findTag to call a logic
`function findClass($class){ $this->findTag('match', $class);}``function match($node, $class){ return preg_match("/" . $class. "/", $node->getAttribute("class"));}`

Comment: Another case need to apply two functions to every node in DOM
`(new Dom)->in('tr')->filter('trim', 'strtolower')`. So "filter" method pass "filterLogic" to your "findTag" with the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use your example! You have a better strategy to handle this?

Comment: Did you read this part `But this is all just an example` & `dont get fully what kind of logic is needed here`? No need do paste next qustion parts in the comment ;-)

Comment: Takes this as answer if its ok. But whatever go and make your next coding steps and if you get stuck again open an new question in SO. thnx and bye